# Adding Authentication to a NodeJS API using AWS Cognito, can i use amlify for that?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my project, I want to implement authentication, and I initially added Amplify to my project because I really liked their API functions. However, I noticed that it contradicts my server since I can't authenticate my APIs with Amplify.

So, what is the correct way to use AWS for authentication with my Node.js server?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement auth by using Cognito directly with your Node.js server using `aws-sdk`:

1. Set Up Amazon Cognito User Pool.
2. Using `aws-sdk` Integrate Cognito with Your Node.js Server.
3. Register Users using Node.js and Cognito `aws-sdk`.
4. Use the `aws-sdk` to call the Cognito API.
5. When a user logs in successfully, Cognito will provide you with JWTs. Your Node.js server can then use these tokens secure the API.
6. Use Cognito User Pools for Authorization.